# What are some of test automation framework design strategies for faster execution of automated tests?

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am attempting to optimize my current automation framework for faster execution. My current framework is designed by keeping separate xml files for locator strings, page objects for each page of my web app which fetch their locator info from these xml files.

But after googling a bit, some automation developers say that keeping those strings inside the page object classes would be more efficient. I need more in-depth details regarding this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you're not looking it from the most appropriate angle. If your current automation process needs considering [Data driven approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_testing) Vs [Page objects](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) when it comes to

> optimize my current automation framework for faster execution.

you're not doing it right. In my experience I've had both implemented and running pretty much independently. First one for functional tests (that don't care so much what the rest of the page is displaying) and for the rendering tests (don't really care about the functionality, if the page layout is as expected). This is the reason why I also ran the UI tests with both [headless ghostDriver](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/46-headless-ghostdriver) and Chrome- Firefox-, IE- Driver.

Let's assume that your data-driven test logic uses something like [CSharp's Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

You only need to load it once and then the search is flat, an *O(1)* [constant time complexity](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-time). Bottom line - such performance shouldn't be an issue unless you have unreasonable large amount of UI tests. Which violates the [Test pyramid](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html):

[image]

If we're going to talk about automation framework optimization for faster execution - [parallel execution](http://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html) of your *x*Unit runner is a good fit.

*Disclaimer:* I'm assuming you are talking UI automation because of the tags you put for this question (*selenium* and *ui-automation*).